# BAM 2.5.0 - Monitoring realtime traffic - Error when creating a new execution plan "Imported streams cannot be empty"

Tags: wso2-bam

New user of the BAM with CEP integration, I'm currently following the "Monitoring Realtime Traffic" sample from WSo2 Doc and block when creating the Execution-plan step. [Link to doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM250/Monitoring+Realtime+Traffic)

The doc requires to

*4. Under Import Stream select  org.wso2.sample.rt.traffic for Import Stream, and enter traffic for As.*

- Unfortunatly when I click "import" nothing happens (in the doc it shows we should get //imported from org.wso2.sample.rt.traffic:1.0.0)
- When I try to add the execution plan I get the "Imported streams cannot be empty"

Am I making a mistake ?

Regards

Vpl

Comment: Check whether the console is logging any errors. Also what's the browser you are using?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Nothing in the console but it works with Mozilla where it does not work on Chrome ... Don't know why. Anyway I was able to continue the sample. Thanks very much

Comment: There are some known issues with IE. But we haven't noticed those with Chrome... what's the Chrome version you are using?

Comment: Hi, I'm back with the same issue. I've installed the BAM on a linux system this time with java 1.8. I've tested with Boss Chrome Version 40.0.2214.111 m and FireFox 35.0.1. With both I have the same issue. Nothing on the logging console. What do you advise me to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue of this UI problem by creating the event stream directly into the registry table. For that I've created the following resource

/_system/governance/StreamDefinitions/org.wso2.sample.rt.traffic/1.0.0

containing

```
{
  "streamId": "org.wso2.sample.rt.traffic:1.0.0",
  "name": "org.wso2.sample.rt.traffic",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "payloadData": [
    {
      "name": "entry",
      "type": "STRING"
    }
  ]
}
```

With a Media Type:  application/json

Then creating the execution plan I could import the event stream and continue the use-case/ / tutorial

Regards